# How to fix CAShapeLayer coming on top of view

Tags: swift, calayer, shadow, cashapelayer

I am adding shadow with the help of CAShapeLayer, but on adding the layer, the shadow is coming on top of view.
I have tried inserting into different positions and adding as sublayer, but in all the cases, its coming on top of View

colorview.drawShadowWithCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 24, shadowColor: .black, shadowOffSet: .zero, shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 5)
[image: Without shadow]

[image: With Shadow]
`

```
func drawShadowWithCornerRadius(cornerRadius: CGFloat, shadowColor: UIColor, shadowOffSet: CGSize, shadowOpacity: Float, shadowRadius: CGFloat) {
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffSet
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        shadowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
    }
```

`

Have tried all methods of inserting layer, but still the layer comes on top of view

Answer (score 0):

You are **adding** a layer with a `shadowMask` ... so it ends up on top of the view's layer.

Instead, you want to add the `shadowMask`, `cornerRadius` and `borderColor` to the view's layer itself:

```
class RhytamShadowView: UIView {
    
    func drawShadowWithCornerRadius(cornerRadius: CGFloat, shadowColor: UIColor, shadowOffSet: CGSize, shadowOpacity: Float, shadowRadius: CGFloat) {
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2

        let pth = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath

        self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowPath = pth
        self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffSet
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius

        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        
        // this does not affect the shadow...
        //self.clipsToBounds = true

    }
    
}
```

**Example controller** - view will start out "plain" ... tap anywhere to apply the shadow:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let rsView = RhytamShadowView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        rsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(rsView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            rsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            rsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            rsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            rsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

        ])

        rsView.backgroundColor = .red
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        rsView.drawShadowWithCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 20.0, shadowColor: .black, shadowOffSet: .zero, shadowOpacity: 0.75, shadowRadius: 8.0)
    }
    
}
```

Output:

[image]